# After signing a certificate using root CA, do we need to recreate ORB

Tags: certificate-authority, java

I have generated a self-signed root CA. Using this root CA, I generated new certificates and activated them on different entities. After this, I re-created [JacORB](https://www.jacorb.org/).

Later, I changed the certificate on the entities and activated it, but I did not re-create JacORB. Due to this, I am getting handshake exceptions on the entities.

Comment: Maybe I'm too stupid, but what are these "ORB" and "entities" things you are talking about? I have the feeling that the question is missing essential context.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've been searching around trying to sort this out, too. I think it is supposed to be "object request broker" but if that's so, then this isn't about TLS or certificates or security.